# Unable to find the required services.Add the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers'inside the call to 'ConfigureServices()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I was following a tutorial of ASP.NET Core MVC web app and then this error generated I tried approximately everything that I know . The `MapDefaultControllerRoute();`is also not working . I also tried shifting from dotnet 6.0 to dotnet core 3.1 but still no progress. Below I'm attaching the error generated and the files:

Error Generated:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.EnsureControllerServices(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)

InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.EnsureControllerServices(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, string name, string pattern, object defaults, object constraints, object dataTokens)
ConsoleApp3.Startup+<>c.<Configure>b__1_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in Startup.cs
+
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder> configure)
ConsoleApp3.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
+
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(object target, object[] arguments, Signature sig, bool constructor, bool wrapExceptions)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.HostingStartup+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.HostingStartup+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
ConsoleApp3.Program.Main(string[] args) in program.cs
+
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

startup.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigurationServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

    }
}
```

HomeController.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController: Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Web Master";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using .net6,you can try to refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Please change name of the method **ConfigurationServices to ConfigureServices**

```
public void ConfigurationServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

to

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Comment: JazakAllah Brother worked for me <3

Comment: Thank you. You can marked it as accepted it will helps others